# Finding a diffeomorphism to put an ODE in a different form.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that you are given a function $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (that is as smooth as you need to assume, I don't really care too much right now about regularity) such that $F(a) = 0, \; a>0, \; \beta = F'(a)>0$.

Then let $\phi$ be a solution to $\phi_r = F(\phi)$ with $\phi \rightarrow a$ as $r \rightarrow - \infty$. (If you need you may assume $\phi >0$ and $\phi_r >0$).

Then I want to prove that there is a smooth diffeomorphism $\psi = \Phi(\phi)$ such that $\psi_r = \beta \psi$.

I have tried all that I can think of to get this result but keep hitting dead ends.

First I differentiated to find an ODE for $\Phi$ but you end up with $\Phi' = \frac{\beta \Phi}{F}$ which has blow up at $a$ unless $\Phi(a) = 0$. Due to the singularity you do not have uniqueness of solutions for this ODE (which is lucky as $\Phi \equiv 0$ is a solution). But then there is no more I can see to do to this ODE?

So I think that the result might be deeper than it appears. My thinking now is that it comes from looking a the Taylor expansion of F about a. Since this is $F(\phi)= 0 + \beta(\phi - a) + ...$. But I cannot see how to get from this local expansion to the desired equation for $\psi$?

The paper this comes from does not make it clear whether the ODE in $\psi$ only holds in a neighbourhood of $r= - \infty$, so can this only be done in this region? The more I consider this the more I am convinced that this can only be a local diffeomorphism.

Could people please comment on the following approach:
Since $\beta > 0$ we have that $F$ is a diffeomorphism in a nbd of a. Then let $\psi = F(\phi)$ in a nbd of $ r\rightarrow - \infty$. Then
\begin{equation} \psi_r = F'(\phi) \phi_r = F'(\phi) \psi \end{equation}
Now (by Taylor) in a nbd of $r \rightarrow -\infty \;\;$ $F'(\phi) = \beta + O(\phi - a)$ so as $\phi \rightarrow a$ (i.e. $r \rightarrow -\infty$) we have that $\psi_r = \beta \psi$.